# Error in using projection system with 1 standard parallel instead of using two?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have to define a new projection system in ArcGIS but to define the system I am having the parameters for Lambert Conformal Conic Projection with 1 standard parallel instead of 2 standard parallel. I want to know how much my locations will deviate.

Comment: The title refers to an "error": exactly what is the erroneous behavior you observe?

Comment: @whuber Actually I am having projection parameters for 1 standard parallel but actually the correct projection what I need is for 2 standard parallels. I am not sure, how much my results (locations) will deviate.